# BigQuery Transpose JSON into columns

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm pretty new to BigQuery and I'm trying to extract some information from a simple JSON field and transpose it into columns.

This is an example of the json on bigquery.

```
[
  {
    "name": "pack",
    "value": "Classic Pack"
  },
  {
    "name": "pack_id",
    "value": 24910
  },
  {
    "name": "pack_count",
    "value": 4
  }
]
```

My desirable table is something like this

```
pack         | pack_id
Classic Pack | 24910
```

I'm struggling to try to use JSON functions but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(json_col) from (
  select json_col, 
    json_value(kv, '$.name') col, 
    json_value(kv, '$.value') value
  from your_table,
  unnest(json_extract_array(json_col)) kv
)
pivot(any_value(value) for col in ('pack', 'pack_id', 'pack_count'))
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Hello Mikail Thanks. It worked =)